# Error: expected ')' in Xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying set a maximum character entry to a UITextField.  I get the following error on the line where I declare the name of the Textfield.

Expected ')'

h file:

```
@interface secondpage : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UITextField *numberTextField;
```

m file:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *numberTextField)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange: 
(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *numberTextField)string {
NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;
return (newLength > 9) ? NO : YES;
}
```

the error I get is on the first line of the m file.  Any hel would be appreciated.

Comment: `replacementString:(NSString *numberTextField)string` -- see anything wrong?

Comment: (Objective-C is dumb, and when it sees `:(ClassName*` it expects a `)` immediately afterwards.  It's not smart enough to tell you that you've got an unnecessary symbol in there.)

Comment: well it's not dumbness, it's syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *numberTextField)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:
```

is incorrect.

It should be

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)numberTextField....
```